# ASP.NET core 1.1.1 and later: send push notification to Android and iOS with Firebase

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, asp.net-core, push-notification

How can I configure my ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 project to send push notifications to Android and iOS phones using the Firebase Framework (FCM)?
PushSharp library is not updated and does not support ASP.NET Core projects. Is there any other library to simplify the integration?

Thank you in advance!